# Updated from 3. to 5.3.0, site gets fatal error

Tags: error, update, fatal

Admin pages work fine, but the site is giving me:

```
Fatal error: Trait 'EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Template\Variables\ModifiableTrait' not found in /home/myuser/public_html/addons/mydomain/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Template.php on line 19
```

Line 19 there looks like:

```
 16   class EE_Template {
 17   
 18     // bring in the :modifier methods
 19     use Template\Variables\ModifiableTrait;
```

Any idea what might be causing it? I don't understand what path that is pointing to or how it's being used.

Comment: What version did you update from? Please be a little more clear. Also, if you upgraded from version `3.x` to `5.3.0` (latest) you're expected to experience some issues. If you can clarify your update/upgrade jump exactly, we can help you more. But if you went from `3.x` to `5.x` regardless, issues are likely. Also, `5.3.0` is bleeding edge so you adopt front-line bugs

Comment: Is there a way I can tell what version I updated from? I don't remember specifically, though I do have the sql db and the files backed up. It's probably in the sql backup somewhere?

Edit?: (6, 1507617158, 'Update complete. Now running version 3.5.11.', NULL, NULL, NULL);